# How to return to initial activity before method is completed?

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog

Assume I have some `Activity` A. `Activity` A has button which calls method `parse()` from class B. `parse()` has boolean check. If it is true `parse()` returns an `Object` (e.g `String`); if it is false `parse()` calls `promtError()` in class B.

Activity A:

```
public class A extends Activity {
 //
 // activity body
 //

 public void onClick(View v){
 String s = B.parse();
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AddToCheckActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("tip", s);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
}
}
```

where `promtError()`:

```
public static void promtError(){
        context = MyApplication.getAppContext();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.getAppContext());
        builder.setMessage("Потеряна связь с сервером. Попробуйте позже.")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

method parse():

```
public String parse(){
    if(a == 1) return generate();
    else promtError();
    return "";
}
```

How should I modify `promtError()` or `parse()` to return to `Activity` A on a moment before I pressed the button on `Activity A`? So i want behaviour similar to GOTO, when promtError() fires, parse() does not do return "" and goes to Activity A, like public void onClick(View v) was never called.

In fact the purpose of this code to protect application from crashes when internet conection is lost. Aplication has many places which call parse(). parse() sends/recieve data to/from server. Thus i hope to add safty chack to parse(), but not to activities that will call it

Comment: why is promtError static?

Comment: Why can't you just have class B return an error code or thown an exception, and then let `Activity` A handle this appropriately by letting A show the message itself?

Just for clarification, is B also an `Activity`? Because I don't see why you would need to go back to `Activity` A in the first place, if you've never left it?

Comment: B is not activity. Reason why i am not doing dialog inside activity A -  i have a lot of activities and dialog message and its reason are same for all activities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How i should modefiy promtError() to return to Activity of A on a moment before i pressed button?

You wanted to say "How do I dismiss the dialog?". Call [`cancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#cancel%28%29) or [`dismiss()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29):

```
public static void promtError() {
    context = MyApplication.getAppContext();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApplication.getAppContext());
    builder.setMessage("Потеряна связь с сервером. Попробуйте позже.")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("закрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: if i simply dismiss dialog will not it remain doing parse() returning "" as result of parse?

Comment: `parse()` will have already returned "" even prior to dismissing the dialog.

Comment: the idea is to prevent return "". I want something similar to goto but now so ugly.

Comment: In `onClick()` check the returned value, i.e. `String s`. If it is empty string ("") do not do anything. And put your new `Intent` before `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: is is nice idia and i considered it before, but generate can output ANY kind of string. In fact the purpose of this code to protect application from crashes when internet conection is lost. Aplication has many places which call parse(). parse() sends/recieve data to/from server. Thus i hope to add safty chack to parse(), but not to activities that will call it.